# How to set up a string type index in the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table that I want to set str into my table index. I am using:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(a, index=a['customerID'].astype(str))
```

But final table looks like this :

[image]

If I am using this code,I got the value. I don't understand why..Please help and thanks in advance

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(a, index=a['customerID'])
```

Comment: df_1.dtypes() tell you the underlying datatype. maybe you are searching for padding?

Comment: `a = a.set_index('customerID')`?

Comment: I just checked the docs, when you call pd.DataFrame with a dataframe as the data and an index, it selects values matching the index from the original dataframe. In your case its empty because you're creating new index values. I'd recommend using .set_index('custimerID') .